# How to enable HTTP access for Django APIs on HTTPS server

Tags: django, ssl, django-rest-framework

I have a website running on a server that redirects all HTTP requests to HTTPS as shown below. I also have a few Django APIs that the server serves (let's say https://www.example.com/apis/log). I am running the Django implementation on Ubuntu + Nginx and have installed SSL certificate using Let's Encrypt.

```
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name xxx.xx.xx.xx example.com www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Now, I would like to do the following:

- Run the website in the present settings (all HTTP requests should redirect to HTTPS)
- Django APIs should work with both HTTP and HTTPS. Hence, I would like to have both http://www.example.com/apis/log and https://www.example.com/apis/log accessible.

Comment: configure `nginx` to serve `api` on `HTTP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    # other directives
}
```

80 - for http and 
443 - for https